# How can I store a temporary value from getSelectedIndex() and use the stored value in another method?

Tags: java

Please take a look at this picture:

[image: Selecting a unit that will become another unit's prequisite]

So when unit is selected, and the user hits on the "**Add Prequisite**" button, whichever unit that is selected will be stored into a temporary instance variable in another class called "**UnitClass**"

A message will be prompt asking the user to select another unit ,  so that the stored value will be passed into the unit's prequisite:

[image: unit details]

What should happen is that the unit Introduction to Business Information Systems's Unit Prerequisite should now be "Test Code" *( Test Name's unit code is Test Code )*

That instance variable is called "temp" with the data type String.

So this is what I tried:
**UnitClass**

```
public void storeUnitPrerequ( String a )
    {
        this.temp = a;
    }

    public String addUnitPrerequ()
    {        
        this.newUnitPrerequ = temp;

        return newUnitPrerequ;    
    }
```

**GUI class**

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( new JFrame() , "Please select a unit to add prequisite." );                                                            

link.storePrerequisite( displayUnitListPane.getSelectedIndex() );

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( new JFrame() , "Now please select where you want the unit you just selected to be a prequisite" );

displayUnitListPane.clearSelection();

link.addPrerequisite( displayUnitListPane.getSelectedIndex() );

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Prerequisite Added!");

link.saveUnit();
```

`link.storePrerequisite()` , `link.addPrerequisite()` and `link.saveUnit()` are all from another control class called "**Apps**"

**Apps class:**

```
public void storePrerequisite( int index )
{
    UnitArray.get(index).storeUnitPrerequ( UnitArray.get(index).getUnitCode() );
}

public void addPrerequisite( int index )
{
    UnitArray.get(index).setUnitPrerequ( UnitArray.get(index).addUnitPrerequ() );
}
```

When this button is clicked, I get indexoutofbounds error - I know what that error means. But how could that be?

Comment: Also, which line do you get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: May be you could post the exception stacktrace.

Comment: @user3580294 at Apps.addPrerequisite(Apps.java:160) and at guiStyle$act.actionPerformed(guiStyle.java:666)

Comment: @Nishan [Exception Stacktrace](http://s15.postimg.org/hq2mbrg3v/pic1.jpg)

Comment: Well, something's wrong, because the index you're requesting is `-1`. What in your code could generate a `-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearing selection with `displayUnitListPane.clearSelection()` just before you call `link.addPrerequisite`.  That is probably the problem.

You could store the selection in a variable and use it.

```
int selection = displayUnitListPane.getSelectedIndex();
link.storePrerequisite( selection );

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( frame , "Now please select where you want the unit you just selected to be a prequisite" );

displayUnitListPane.clearSelection();
link.addPrerequisite ( selection );
```